# Web based photo album organizer for Java EE 6

Tags: java-ee-6

Is there anything similar to [web based photo album organizer Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/), but for Java EE 6? I was using this but now I have moved to Java EE 6. Will I need to write my own album organizer?

Comment: I know of no gallery-type software for Java EE, you could try using [Caucho Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) to integrate Gallery into your JavaEE container?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. After extensive search on the web without any solution I have began to wonder if it is possible to integrate PHP code. Will definitely give it a try if no other solution is presented.

Comment: I haven't used it in production yet, but the tests were very encouraging after some initial setup pains - but the available documentation is a lot better now.  The [wiki](http://wiki3.caucho.com/Quercus:_Gallery2) even has a dedicated entry for Gallery

Comment: I have noticed that entry about Gallery in wiki. To bad it is for version 2. I guess it is not very different for version 3.